# Changing the Default colour of Promoted LInks

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

I have used code to change the size of the promoted links on a page.  However, I cannot change the background default colour of the actual promoted links frame which I think is part of the theme.

As a result this is what it looks like:
[image: Resized Promoted LInks]

I have tried changing the size of the images to take up the full size of the tile but this has no effect and the rest of the space for the tile is red.  I would like to change the colour to white so that the difference in sizes of tiles are not that noticeable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version? SP Online or on-premise?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Within the Style block, I added:

```
div.ms-tileview-tile-content {
    background-color: white;
}
```